# Issue populating TEMP_TABLE from sys_refcursor

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I have two procedures in Oracle SQL. One opens a sys_refcursor (as an out parameter) and grabs data from a large table (via SELECT statements) and does some filtering giving a desired result set. Now what I want to do is retain that data for use in another procedure via a global temp table (ultimate goal is to package both procedures up). Below is my code for the second procedure, where I run the first procedure from the second and then fetch from the sys_refcursor from the first procedure to populate my temp table.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE TEST_PROCEDURE (
STARTD DATE, ENDD DATE, TID VARCHAR2) AS 
L_RC SYS_REFCURSOR;
L_REC TEMP_TABLE%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
   FILTER_DATA_WITH_PEAK(L_RC, STARTD, ENDD, TID);
   LOOP
      FETCH L_RC
        INTO L_REC;
      EXIT WHEN L_RC%NOTFOUND;
      INSERT INTO TEMP_TABLE(STARTDATE, ENDDATE, ATTRIBUTE_TXGRID, ATTRIBUTE_PNOM,
      ATTRIBUTE_QNOM, INTERVALVALUE) VALUES 
      (L_REC.STARTDATE, L_REC.ENDDATE, L_REC.ATTRIBUTE_TXGRID, 
      L_REC.ATTRIBUTE_PNOM, L_REC.ATTRIBUTE_QNOM, L_REC.INTERVALVALUE);
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE L_RC;
END TEST_PROCEDURE;
```

The issue is that even though this code saves without errors and runs without errors, my temp table is still empty. There has to be some minute issue here with my code, especially since if I replace the whole insert into... command with a dbms_output.put_line command the right data will show up so I know that I am fetching the data correctly...

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You realize the temp table is only visible per oracle session?

Comment: Are you checking the table from a different session; or committing before checking and your GTT is set to delete on commit, maybe? Side issue, but why isn't your first procedure populating the GTT and returning a ref cursor of a select from that?

Comment: So should I just use a regular table instead? I thought global temp tables in oracle behaved a lot like regular ones if you preserve rows on commit..

Comment: @wbrugato - Do you need the data to be available to a different Oracle session?  You could use a permanent table but then you'd have to include some sort of additional key that would identify which rows relate to a particular call.  And you'd have to write code to clean up the table when the data is no longer needed.

Comment: I got this working by making the Temp_table not an actual temp table. Its as you guys said, the table was from a different session. I am not experienced with SQL and will have to look into how to get that to work :C

For now though, before the loop that populates the table I run a delete from temp_table to clean the table each time the procedure is called.